# Process is shutting down when started by script and special user

Tags: script, process, nohup

I have a situation where I want to use a script during a build process which stops a process and starts it again after updating its files as a last step. 
The process is started via a build system which uses an own user account on the machine.

The script works fine when starting it manually but when the build system starts it, it will shut down after a few seconds.

Has anybody any idea why the process is shutting down?

P.S.: I am using nohup and & when starting the process.
P.P.S: I tried to redirect the in- and output, but this didn't help...

Comment: STOP you mean pause ? or terminate ?

Comment: Does the build system's user have the permissions required for the resources used by the script?  Have you considered adding logging to your script so you can see what's going on?

Comment: It is terminated with "kill xy". 

The script has all the permissions needed, but I think I wasn't very clear in my problem description: 
The script itself is running succesfully. It starts another process which works, but after a few seconds this second process (not the script) is terminated...